# How send a keys combination using win api?

Tags: c#, winapi

How send a keys combination using win api?

For example, CTRL + A or CTRL + SHIFT + I

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const UInt32 WM_UP = 0x0101;
const int key_ctrl = 0xA2;
const int key_a = 0x41;

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, key_ctrl, 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, key_a, 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_UP, key_a, 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_UP, key_ctrl, 0);
```

Comment: Ever since Windows Vista, devs should not rely on `PostMessage` to send key strokes to another process.  Consider using _Microsoft UI Automation_ instead

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). Instead, you can use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput), or, even better, [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview).

Comment: @mic: Nothing to do with Windows Vista. This has *always* been unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

UI Automation really fits, thanks

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
SendKeys.SendWait("^+{i}")
```

Comment: SetForegroundWindow nor SendWait are part of UI Automation... Focus could change between the two calls and you could send the keys to another window.